# Multi-line foreach loop in linq / lambda

Tags: linq, lambda, foreach

I am looking for a way to change the following code:

```
foreach (Contact _contact in contacts)
{
    _contact.ID = 0;
    _contact.GroupID = 0;
    _contact.CompanyID = 0;
}
```

I would like to change this using LINQ / lambda into something similar to:

```
contacts.ForEach(c => c.ID = 0; c.GroupID = 0; c.CompanyID = 0);
```

However that doesn't work. Is there any way to do multi-line in a linq foreach other than by writing a function to do this in one line?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
contacts.ForEach(c => { c.ID = 0; c.GroupID = 0; c.CompanyID = 0; });
```

It doesn't have anything to do with LINQ per se; it's just a simple anonymous method written in lambda syntax passed to the `List<T>.ForEach` function (which existed since 2.0, before LINQ).

Comment: I was looking for a way to do multi-line statements in LINQ Select.  The ForEach syntax allows me to do this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

LINQ stands for Language Integrated **Query** - which means it is intended for *querying* - i.e. extracting or transforming a sequence into a new set, not manipulating the original.

The [`ForEach` method hangs off `List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) and is a convenience shortcut to foreach; nothing special.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.  It seems somewhat similar to the map function in ES6.